# DynamicReports doesn't apply pattern to format ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime-format, dynamic-reports, zoneddatetime

I have a model class that contains field of type [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). When generate report data is shown as:

> 2017-08-17T16:09:03+03:00[Europe/Chisinau]

To format that date I use method `setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")` but nothing changes.

All stuff is generated via reflection, check source:

```
for (Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    String fieldName = field.getName();
    if (usedFields.contains(fieldName)) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class) || field.getType().isAssignableFrom(ZonedDateTime.class)){
            report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, field.getType()).setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        }else {
            report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, field.getType()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Generate report** where *list* is a generic list of elements.

```
report
.title(
        Components.text("Documents Report")
        .setStyle(getHeaderCenteredBoldStyle())
        .setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER))
        .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
.setColumnTitleStyle(getColumnTitleStyle())
.highlightDetailEvenRows()
.setDataSource(list);
```

**Generated PDF**

[image: generated pdf]
Any ideas?

Comment: What does the actual rendering do? It's not enough to just call `toString()` on a thing, you would have to format your dateTimes, and your output looks exactly like `toString()` result.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov check updates, how can I format this. date. All that I found in exaples is *setPattern()* method. Check for updates in answer

Comment: It would seem to me that your version of `DynamicReports` doesn't support `java.time` library. Since you seem to build it via reflection anyway, try using `setPatternExpression` method where you'd use proper formatter expression code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `setPattern` works fine for `java.util.Date`, but not for `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. I've created a simple entity:

```
public class Entity {

    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-08-17T16:09:03+03:00[Europe/Chisinau]");

    private Date date = new Date();

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then I've used your code (`for (Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields()) etc`) to add the columns. For the data source `list`, I've created it manually, just to test:

```
DRDataSource ds = new DRDataSource("zonedDateTime", "date");
ds.add(entity.getZonedDateTime(), entity.getDate());
```

In the resulting report, the `ZonedDateTime` wasn't formatted (it's shown as `2017-08-17T16:09:03+03:00[Europe/Chisinau]`), but the `Date` was correctly displayed as `21.08.2017`.

One way to fix this is to set a value formatter and use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to convert the `ZonedDateTime` to a `String`:

```
if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(ZonedDateTime.class)) {
    // ZonedDateTime, use a value formatter
    report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, ZonedDateTime.class)
        // set a custom value formatter
        .setValueFormatter(new AbstractValueFormatter<String, ZonedDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public String format(ZonedDateTime value, ReportParameters reportParameters) {
                // convert ZonedDateTime to dd.MM.yyyy format
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
                return value.format(fmt);
            }
        }));
} else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)) {
    // java.util.Date: setPattern works
    report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, field.getType()).setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
...
```

With this, the `ZonedDateTime` is displayed with the format defined in the `DateTimeFormatter`:

> 17.08.2017

In this example I'm creating the `DateTimeFormatter` inside the inner class, but it's better to create just one formatter outside of the `if` (it can be in a `static final` field, as it's immutable and thread-safe) and reuse it accross your application.

---

Another alternative is to manually format the `ZonedDateTime` to a `String`, using the same `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, but in the data source list. I also had to change the type of the column to `String` (inside the `for`):

```
if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(ZonedDateTime.class)) {
    // ZonedDateTime, manually convert to String
    report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, String.class));
} else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)) {
    // java.util.Date: setPattern works
    report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, field.getType()).setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
} else {
    report.addColumn(Columns.column(fieldName, fieldName, field.getType()));
}
```

Then, in the data source `list`, I had to use the `DateTimeFormatter` to format the `ZonedDateTime` to a `String`:

```
// create formatter
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

// format the ZonedDateTime
ds.add(entity.getZonedDateTime().format(fmt), entity.getDate());
```

With this, the `ZonedDateTime` is now shown as `17.08.2017`.

I'm not sure how you're creating the `list` of values, but you'll have to change it to format the `ZonedDateTime` in the way described above (or do it internally in the entity).